# How can I change 'no rows to show' to some custom component ag-grid react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid for react https://www.ag-grid.com and when my table/grid is empty it shows "No rows to show", I need to change it to some custom message/component but could not find any mention of it in docs. It is possible to do using  API ?

Answer (score 0):

with the prop "overlayNoRowsTemplate" :

```
<AgGridReact
    rowData={data}
    defaultColDef={{...defaultColDef, valueSetter}}
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    overlayNoRowsTemplate={"bla"}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
const gridRef = useRef(null);

<AgGridReact
  ref={gridRef}
  rowData={data}
  defaultColDef={{...defaultColDef, valueSetter}}
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
  overlayNoRowsTemplate={'<span aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true";pos>No data Available!</span>'}
/>
```

Use the useRef and overlayNoRowsTemplate functions of AGGrid.

```js
 if (data.length === 0) {
    gridRef.current.api.showNoRowsOverlay();
} else {
    gridRef.current.api.hideOverlay();
}
```

and add this where you set the data.